# JavaScript can't add contenteditable attribute

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

JavaScript:

```js
var insertImage = function(src, alt) {
   var html = '<div contenteditable="false"><img ' + 'src="'+src+'" alt="'+alt+'" onclick="imageClick()" /></div>';
   document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, html);
};
```

HTML:

```html
<body>
  <div id="yq_editor_content" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow: hidden; background-color:lightblue;" contenteditable="true">
  </div>
  <div id="yq_editor_footer"></div>
</body>
```

But after I perform the JavaScript function, I get the HTML that `div` has no   `contenteditable`, as below:

[image]

Comment: can you please properly format the code?

Comment: I guess that `contenteditable="false"` is ignored because it's unnecessary.

Comment: @Aloso, but I need it. If I don`t add the attribute, "img" can`t perform the function "imageClick"

Comment: Did you try `el.contentEditable = false` or `el.setAttribute("contenteditable", "false")`?

Comment: If you need the `contenteditable` attribute inside `imageClick()`, instead of checking if it's false, try checking if it's true... like `el.getAttribute("contenteditable") && doSomething()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/_jserodio/ywe48rwy/

**JavaScript, CSS and HTML**

```js
  

var insertImage = function(src, alt) {
   var img = '<img ' + 'src="'+src+'" alt="'+alt+'"/>';
   document.querySelector('#yq_editor_content').innerHTML += img;
};

document.querySelector('#insert').addEventListener("click", function() {
    insertImage('http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico', 'so');
}, false);
```

```css
#insert {
  width: 25px;
  heigth: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="yq_editor_content" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow: hidden; background-color:lightblue;" contenteditable="true">
  Hello, try to edit this!
</div>
<div id="yq_editor_footer">
  <img id ='insert' src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/256/Actions-insert-image-icon.png" alt="insert image icon">
</div>
```

Comment: I can`t always add "div" or other tags in your way.

Comment: You asked this: _But after I perform the JavaScript function, I get the HTML that div has no contenteditable, as_ and I provided you the code in which the `div` now includes this `contenteditable`. What are you exactly asking for? I guess I didn't understand you well, I'm sorry.

Comment: Sorry, my English is weak. I want create a TextEditor, when I click a button I can insert an image in my TextEditor. I need the image can response "imageClick" function. But the tag I inserted has no "contenteditable" attribute, so it can`t reponse "imageClick" function. And I wish I can insert a lot of images.

Comment: @留什么白could you please provide me the code for imageClick function? what does it do? Are you supposed to click an icon, and this imageClick will insert an image?

Comment: Something like this? You click on the +, and it will insert an image. All the content is editable. https://jsfiddle.net/_jserodio/ywe48rwy/

Comment: This is my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/yuyedaidao/q548qatp). It`s good in pc browser although "contenteditable" is still ignored, but bad in mobile browser. When I click img,it  still can`t perform imageClick function.

Comment: I'm sorry @留什么白 I don't think I can help you with that.